# setting value dynamically when old value changed

Tags: angularjs

I have a function `mycredits();` to get number of credits available . I have to show it as my notification , when I do certain operation like adding user or offering user, my credits will get reduced. but now I navigate to one page to another only this is working , in same page the credits values are not getting refreshed.

```
$scope.mycredits = function(){
    $scope.totalCredits = response.json.response.data.totalcredits;
}

$scope.addUser = function(){
if(statuscode == 0){
$scope.mycredits();
}
}
```

my html :

```
     <a href="#/credits">
  <i class="fa fa-money"></i> 
<span>CREDITS</span>
 <span class="creditBlock" >{{totalCredits}}</span> 
    </a>
```

Comment: include a working example, where issue can be reproduced. So others can debug it & help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs: ng-model doesn't refresh after object change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197349/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-refresh-after-object-change)

Comment: Let me kinow if my answer is helpful , if not ,then explain the scenario better i.e. are you using 2 controllers or doing in the same one

Comment: your controller and html are of same page?

Comment: its in a same html , but different controllers

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it worked for you then. Also, try not to use `$rootScope.totalCredits` as its a bad practive to declare global variables. Go for `events` so that you can trigger other changes in the controller if you place them in `$rootScope.$on` function

Comment: Added a plunkr in my answer. take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from your scenario, **you are changing credit in one `controller` & you are showing the `credit` value changes in another `controller`**.

Try emitting `events` from the controller *where you are changing the credit value*

```
$scope.mycredits = function(){
  $scope.totalCredits = response.json.response.data.totalcredits;
  $rootScope.$emit('credit-changed',$scope.totalCredits);
}
```

and in the another controller where you are displaying the `credits`, listen to the events like:

```
$rootScope.$on('credit-changed',function(event,data){
    $scope.credit = data;
})
```

[Check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/nAml1MBJRt7RAKZOLNDv?p=preview)

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon : In your scenario, using `rootScope` will not give you any noticeable performance improvement. not even of a sec, & this approach is not something that you can `expand` in future to incorporate more things on `credit` change.  check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761540/why-using-rootscope-with-functions-is-not-recommended. Use the better approach than working on some "one type" scenario. Also, check `comment` in my `js` file of updated plunkr

Answer (score 1):

Assign,`totalCredits` using `$rootScope.totalCredits` and in `html` use thew same `{{totalCredits}}` it will work across all `controllers`

**Controller:**

```
$scope.credits = {};

$scope.mycredits = function(){
    $rootScope.totalCredits = response.json.response.data.totalcredits;
}

$scope.addUser = function(){
    if(statuscode == 0){
        $scope.mycredits();
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#/credits">
    <i class="fa fa-money"></i> 
    <span>CREDITS</span>
    <span class="creditBlock" >{{totalCredits}}</span> 
</a>
```

Comment: assign `$rootScope.totalCredits`, it will work. please check my answer

Comment: try not to use `$rootScope.totalCredits` as its a bad practice to declare global variables. Go for events so that you can **trigger other changes** in the controller if you place them in `$rootScope.$on` function. which you cant do without `$watch` in your case(which will be overkill and bad pratice)

Comment: even events will take more overhead, since the events will be added on `rootScope`, assiging a `variable` takes less `overhead` than `events`. Also main reason not to use events here because he is on the same page, but differeent controllers

Comment: Good point ! but what if in future the user wants to do more with change in `credits` ?  not just displaying the value. it cant be expanded in future that easily.

Comment: even if he changes any value, it can be updated using `rootScope` and also `rootScope` works generally as a scope but among different `controllers`. So he can even play with that variable around.

Comment: since you have a single page, `event emitter`will be heavy code to register and `emit` events. It may cost performance. So I gave you a simple answer using a `variable`

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible  reasons/solutions for that

1. You need to add a $watch so you get a hook when the value changes 
   more info can be found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/)
2. You need to activate the Digest Loop after the update more info [here](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/)
3. Maybe it's better not to use the watch for such feature but fire an [event](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx)